# Augmented Reality SDK that will show pipe lines using GIS data

Tags: gis, sdk

I need AR SDK that will show pipe lines using GIS data for field crew.

Wikitude and layar have GEO support. But none of them is supporting lines. We talked with these companies they have no solution about it. Also I found this but his site is down. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zwx5CQq94E

Do you suggest any SDK or approach about it?

Comment: Layer supports POI points.